# Hololens doesn't detect Wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, hololens

At first, my Wifi network was detected by the Hololens, but after entering the password, it disappeared from the list, and the device is not connected.

- The network is not visible in the list of saved networks (in fact, I cleared that list entirely)
- I do see all the neighbor's networks
- Restarting the modem/router did not help.
- Other devices can connect to Wifi without any problem

What could be the problem? Is there a way to reset just the network settings?

One thing that I can think of, is that the hololens's date and time were off by a few years when I tried to connect. I have now adjusted it so they are roughly correct, but I still don't see my network.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Hololens does not like it when the Wifi router has both 2.4 and 5 GHz enabled. After disabling 2.4 GHz, I can connect to Wifi.

Why it did see the network initially, I can't say.